# How does Falcon 9 differ from Shuttle or Apollo inertial guidance?

Tags: falcon-9, navigation

I read a very detailed analysis of the Saturn V.  From it I learned there is a computer and guidance "room" which is an extra slice of rocket stacked between the 2nd or 3rd launch stages and the the rest of the rocket.

This writeup said that all of the pre-orbit systems were run from this slice, and it was disposed of along with the last launch rocket in space.

One of the challenges with this is that there was an inertial navigation system of physical gyros that needed aligning just prior to launch.  This was accomplished by having a laser at as precise known point near the launch site.  There was a corresponding quartz "window" on the spacecraft that the laser was pointed at that allowed the inertial system to align itself until just before launch.  The INS looked at this up until something like 30 seconds prior to launch.  The writeup said that, in fact, this led to  small error due to earth's rotation - but this got fixed as a fine tuning adjustment at orbital levels.

How did the Shuttle differ from this?  And, how does the Falcon 9 accomplish the task?

Comment: Shuttle had an inertial guidance system that was conceptually similar. You can read about it on page 2.13-7 of this document. https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf Not writing an answer because I don't know anything about Falcon.